# Including movie in keynote presentation and then converting it to pdf

Tags: video, pdf, keynote

I have to make a presentation containing some videos using Keynote. After making the presentation when I export it to pdf, the image appears on the slide but not the video. I am new to keynote presentation. So, can anyone tell me how to include a movie in pdf exported from a Keynote presentation ?

Comment: It is not really possible since the pdf file format does not allow the inclusion of movies. AFAIK the only option would be to make every single frame a new slide in the pdf.

Comment: can I include it as gif

Comment: PDFs cannot contain movies or animated GIFs. If you must have those movies in a self contained file, the whole thing should be an GIF animation or a movie like MP4 or QuickTime.

Comment: Sure you can embed movies in PDF, since Acrobat 9. Of course, that doesn't mean anyone other than Adobe has actually implemented it, but the file format allows for it. https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/acrobat/using/rich-media.html